# Arrange $Title horizontally in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

How do I arrange `$Title` horizontally in SilverStripe with the following HTML code?

```
<div class="content-container unit size3of4 lastUnit">
    <article>
        <h1>$Title</h1>
        <% loop $Children %>
            <div class="item col-md-6">
                <h3>
                    <a href="$Link">$Title</a>
                </h3>
            </div>
        <% end_loop %>
    </article>

    $Form
    $CommentsForm
</div>
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want to do, which $Title are you referring to? Some examples of end result will help.

Comment: This is a css issue. Hard to tell without knowing the css. So please provide some more information: Which $Title do you want to make horizontal? What css or css framework are you using? I guess you need something like a block-grid (like foundation has, see http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html)

Comment: I wanted to make the child $Title horizontal.  So if I have 12 children $Title, I can have for example 4 rows of 3 $Title arranged horizontally. I'm not using framework.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this with some simple css.

We use `float: left` on the `.item` div to make items layout side by side.

We then set a `width` of 25% (or a margin and width that equal 25%). We can add some margin to ensure there is some spacing between the items.

Finally we add some css to `article` to clear the floating items. We do this so any content below the floating items appears correctly.

**CSS**

```css
.content-container article .item {
    float: left;
    width: 22%;
    margin-right: 3%;
}
.content-container article:before,
.content-container article:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.content-container article:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

**[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kaa7fhzc/1/)**